# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: python

Удалил Python с компьютера и установил заново. Теперь при запуске программ выдаёт следующую ошибку.
Сразу полез гуглить - пишут, то переустанови Python - не помогает, то установи PYTHONHOME. А как его установить? Погуглил и не нашёл как это сделать.
В системных штуках я новичок, подскажите пожалуйста, что надо установить или куда нажать чтобы всё заработало? Запускаю код, как и всегда, через VS Code.

```
[Running] python -u "c:\StudioCode\neural-network-master\lesson 7. keras_grads.py"
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python38.zip',
    'D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.8',
    'D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.8',
    'D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000804 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.064 seconds
```

Апдейт. Теперь выдаёт следующее и так и не запускает программу:

```
PS C:\StudioCode\neural-network-master> & "C:/Program Files/MSYS2/mingw64/bin/python.exe" c:/StudioCode/neural-network-master/7.py
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\wonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Users\wonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38'
  program name = 'C:\Program Files\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python38.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8\\lib-dynload',  
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding   
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003148 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Comment: Первый сайт по запросу `pythonhome` - https://evileg.com/ru/post/327/

Comment: Там написано:
" В командной строке введите путь %path%;C:\Python и нажмите Enter. Примечание. C:\Python - это путь к каталогу Python. "

У меня при запуске через cmd:
%path%;C:\Users\wonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
выдаёт:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Откройте командную строку от имени администратора и напишите `setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\path\to\python"` - это изменит переменную `PATH`. Если нужны и другие переменные - делайте таким же способом или через *gui* в панели упраления

Comment: Получил сообщение:
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

Но вопрос так и не решился, всё то же самое, как и в начале.

Comment: Вопрос ещё не решился, но прогресс есть! С PYTHONHOME и PYTHONPATH помог запуск cmd от имени администратора, и ввод setx /M PYTHONHOME "C:\path\to\python". И так же для PYTHONPATH. Теперь хотя бы при вводе в cmd "python", появляется инфо о версии Python.